# Lets Encrypt and Too many redirects

Tags: apache, xampp, lets-encrypt

I'm using PufferPanel to manage my game servers and I have run into a problem with the SSL certificate step. I'm using Lets Encrypt to generate a certificate and with that comes system files verification to make sure it is authentic. I can't get the .well-known to work as Pufferhost must have something within its JS which redirects anything to a 404 page. I found some resources online and came up with the configuration below. Unfortunately, it does not work. It shows a chrome error saying that I am performing too many redirects, how can I fix this. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
##################################################################################################
#                               PANEL VIRTUAL HOST                                              #
##################################################################################################
    <VirtualHost *:80 *:8080 *:443>
        ServerName panel.example.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The vhost listen to Port 8080 and then redirect to Port 8080, that should be the loop.

I would suggest to use individual vhosts for each Port.
One for Port 80 HTTP and one for Port 443 HTTPS. Port 8080 needs no vhost because you redirect to it.
Then you can use the Vhost with Port 80 with a DocumentRoot where Lets-encrypt can store the .well-known/acme-challenge/.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName www.example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName www.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"

</VirtualHost>
```

When you have the Lets Encrypt Certificate you can add an redirect from Port 80 to Port 443 to force HTTPS. Then you need to add the SSL-Certificate to the Port 443 vhost config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName www.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8080/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Depending on your OS the SSLCertificateFile/SSLCertificateKeyFile-Path is at an other location.